# Basic pointer to array of class for c++

Tags: c++, class

```
AIBase* allai[2];
AIBase *z0AI = new AIA;
    AIBase *z1AI = new AIB;
allai[0] = z0AI;//this this gives me an error
allai[1]= z1AI;
```

AIBase is the superclass and AIA and AIB  inherits from the AIBase
what is wrong with the syntax ,i need some help in figuring this out
error 1:

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
error C2040: 'allai' : 'int []' differs in levels of indirection from 'AIBase *[2]'

Why must this code be in function scope? Cant this work in global scope?

Comment: Please don't make us guess. Show the error message (it's important).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this snippet. http://ideone.com/UEC0k

Comment: Do you write it in function scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ (and C), executable code that is not a variable initialiser *must* appear inside a function. Executable code cannot appear at file scope (that is, outside any function).

So, just put your code inside a function:

```
int main(int, char *[])
{
    AIBase* allai[2];
    AIBase *z0AI = new AIA;
    AIBase *z1AI = new AIB;
    allai[0] = z0AI;
    allai[1]= z1AI;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. However, to be pedantic, it's only the last two lines that need to be inside a function; the first three can appear at file scope. (Not that it's recommended...)